# Using if with my foreach structure

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I am using the following structure for my foreach how would I use an if statement within the same format?

```
<?php foreach($property as $section):?>


    if(!empty($section))
    {
      echo <p>data here </p>;
    }else{
      html
    }

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: "within the same format" - what does that mean?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev using the endforeach and :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($property as $section):
    if(!empty($section)):
      echo "<p>data here </p>";
    endif;
endforeach;?>
```

OR

```
<?php foreach($property as $section):
    if(!empty($section)):
      echo "<p>data here </p>";
    else:
       echo "html";
    endif;
endforeach;?>
```

See: [Alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: fixed open/close tags and echo quotes

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but you don't have valid php.

```
foreach($property as $section) {
    if(!empty($section))
    {
      echo '<p>data here </p>';
    }else{
      echo 'html';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

```
<?php foreach($property as $section): ?>
    <?php
        if(!empty($section)) :
            echo <p>data here </p>;
        else :
            html
        endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

SHORTHAND :

```
<?php foreach($property as $section):?>
    <?php if(!empty($section)):?>
      <p>data here </p>;
    <?php else: ?>
      html
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

OTHER:

```
<?php foreach($property as $section)
 {
   if(!empty($section))
   {
     echo '<p>data here </p>';
   }else{
       echo 'html';
   }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example containing `}elseif{` also:

```
<?php foreach($property as $section):?>

<?php    if(!empty($section)): ?>

      <p>data here </p>

<?php   elseif ([another condition]): ?>

      ...

<?php   else: ?>

      html

<?php   endif: ?>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

The entire documentation is here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution for this is:

```
<?php
foreach($property as $section) {
    if(!empty($section))
    {
        echo '<p>data here </p>';
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <div id="dosome">really crazy html stuff here</div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```